# Btn-toolbar / input-append migration from Bootstrap 2 to 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I had a toolbar using Bootstrap 2:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
  <a class="btn" href="adicionar/">Adicionar cliente</a>
  <form class="pull-right" method="GET">
    <fieldset class="input-append search">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="id_search" class="input-medium" maxlength="200">
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-group" name="submit_search" value="Buscar">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

Then according to the docs, I should just put a .btn-default in the .btn and change .input-append to .input-group. Like:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
  <a class="btn btn-default" href="adicionar/">Adicionar cliente</a>
  <fieldset class="input-group search">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="id_search" class="input-medium" maxlength="200">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-group" name="submit_search" value="Buscar">
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

The result is just terrible! The buttons lose styling and the are not inline anymore. Any hint on how to solve that?

Comment: You are not incuding `.btn-default` in the button element, instead you are adding `.btn-group`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final code was:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="adicionar/">Adicionar cliente</a>
      <form class="col-md-3 input-group pull-right" method="GET">   
      <input type="text" name="search" id="id_search" class="input-medium form-control" maxlength="200">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-group" name="submit_search" value="Buscar">
      </span>
    </form>
</div>
```

Solved.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this.. Notice the `input-group-btn` span..

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <a class="btn btn-default" href="adicionar/">Adicionar cliente</a>
    <div class="col-md-3 input-group pull-right">
      <input type="text" name="search" id="id_search" class="input-medium form-control" maxlength="200">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-group" name="submit_search" value="Buscar">
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/77949

Comment: My form just don't work. Just change the div for <form class="col-md-3 input-group pull-right" method="GET">, I will put this as the correct answer. Still, it doesn't align well on firefox, but is perfect on chrome =(

Answer (score 0):

From docs:

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
</div>
```

For button toolbar then:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SBSgN/1/

Is that what you want?

Comment: @StaticX did you check the jsfiddle link?

Comment: @StaticX check the fiddle modification: http://jsfiddle.net/SBSgN/2/ do you need the form to be embedded in a toolbar?

Comment: Yes, but <input type="text" class="btn btn-default"/> doesn't seem ok. It is an input text not a button.. see in jsfiddle you can click on it as if it were a button!